# How does MongoDB decide which single field index to use when duplicates exist for the same field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

It is possible for two single field indexes to be created for the same field when one is ascending and the other descending.

While testing this I have found that a basic 'where' query on such a field will always use the descending index regardless of which options either index has that may affect the search.

For the problem I am trying to solve I have one index that is unique and is partial based on if the particular field exists (and as such is not null) and another that is non-unique on the same field so that any queries for documents with that field as null do not lead to a collection scan.

Queries of that collection for documents with a specific non-null field will always use the descending index - even if in this case that happens to be the non-unique index that contains the documents with a null field whereas the ascending index does not.

Answer (score 1):

The first time the query planner sees a specific query shape, it runs a planning phase were it considers the applicable indexes, runs the query for a short time using each index, then selects the plan that returned the most documents with the least work.  It caches the selected plan so planning does not need to be done every time a query is run. See [Query Plans](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-plans/index.html#query-plans) for more info.

You can see the plans that were considered for a specific query and how each performed using [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/index.html#db-collection-explain) with the "allPlansExection" option.

The query executor can use an index in either forward or backward direction.  Which is used is indicated in the explain plan.

This means the if you are querying on `{key: xxx}` or sorting by `{key:1}` the index `{key:-1}` can be used.

i.e. creating both an ascending and descending index for the same single-field index is a waste of space and processing power.

In your case, one of the index is partial, so when the query planner checks, it should find that the partial index performs much better than the other index.

However, there is usually a restriction from creating an index on the same fields with different options, and you seem to have bypassed that by reversing the sort order.  I'm don't know if that will confuse the query planner, so you should probably test explain with the various queries you intend to use to make sure it does what you expect.

If the query planner does not consistently select the correct index, you can hint which one you want to be used and bypass having the planner test any others.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I couldn't find an answer in the documentation and this is an odd scenario because the original partial index solves the actual problem for me but I'm trying to solve the edge case of stopping a full collection scan if ever a search is done for a null value for that field. This should never actually happen but a search on this collection not using an index would be terrible for this use case.

Comment: Essentially I would like to be able to tell the collection to always use that index even if a search is undertaken against something explicitly excluded from the partial index filter (and so will always return 0 results even if there in theory could be some). It's being too clever for its own good and identifying that is the case - discarding the partial index and looking at every document.

Comment: You can use `hint()` to tell it which index to use by name.